# Python mypy-mirror in precommit, how to find a list of additional dependencies

Tags: python, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I have .pre-commit set with the following config:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [types-requests,types-python-dateutil,types-PyYAML]
```

I wonder where this types- comes from. I tried to add a few, like say: `types-boto3` it works, but I do not understand why (or rather: to what it's mapped, by whom, and where is it defined).

I tried googling for the list of possible additional dependencies but my googling skills are not good enough. For example, googling after `types-boto3` leads me to: https://mypy-boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. But again, why?

Comment: Try `mypy --install-types` to find some common ones used in your code. The rest can be detected with `ignore_missing_imports = false` in config file (you'll get a bunch of `module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker  [import]` errors. For boto3, `mypy` found wrong types: you should use `boto3-stubs[s3,lambda]` (services you use enumerated as optional deps). You can read about files source [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-install-types).

Comment: they are just packages on pypi -- https://pypi.org/p/types-requests for example